# Autonomous vehicle with SLAM

Tags: robotics

I have an idea for a project I want to build but I do not know how to do it. I hate cutting grass every week so I would like to build an autonomous lawn mower. I have a (quite) small garden and I would like to have a robot capable of mapping it by itself and cutting all of it, remembering where he is already passed and avoiding obstacles. I think a Raspberry with a LIDAR could be enough for the logic and mapping part, maybe adding an Arduino to control the power section (motor, blades, etc). I would like to know from you if you think this is reasonable or not. What I think would be the most difficult part is the mapping part: can you suggest me any libraries I could use to do that? I tried to search on the internet but even though I found some examples of raspberry powered little robots I could not find anything detailed enough with a mapping part.
I know I have still a lot to learn and I do not expect to have a working prototype soon, I will take this as a good learning opportunity. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few videos on YouTube but the main process is known as SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping).

For the robotic side you could look at the [Robot Operating System](https://wiki.ros.org/) Wiki and they have section that ties them together [here (gmapping)](https://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping)